# Is there a limit to how much data can be retrieved from a data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, landing-page

I contacted SFMC tech support to ask about a limit on the number of rows that can be retrieved on a microsite landing page.  First level support told me there isn't and there must be something wrong with the ampscript on my page which I don't believe is the case. He suggested I ask about it here.

So, if I use the code below to get the data, it gets about 300 rows and although it sometimes runs a little slowly, it does work:

```
LOOKUPROWS("My_Data_Extension", "Status", "M")
```

If I change it to the following where it would be pulling a couple thousand rows, it runs for a while and then throws me out to a 404 error page.

```
LOOKUPROWS("My_Data_Extension", "Status", "R")
```

My thought is that it is timing out pulling back all the data or that it is finding that it is too large of a data set. There are a fair number of fields in the DE and 2 of them are large text fields (think comment fields on contact forms).  Is there any other way to get the data?  I don't need the full row. Is there any way to specify returning only specific fields? Would that even help if I need to get back a couple thousand rows? Is there a limit to how many rows I can get back?

Answer (score 1):

There is a default limit of 2000 rows returned via AMPScript and SSJS.  You can get around this by placing a number inside of the LookUpOrderedRows call:

e.g. LOOKUPORDEREDROWS('My_Data_Extension', 2500,'Status','Status','R')

If you want to pull the total count of the DE, you can get around placing a defined number by using the AMPScript function DataExtensionRowCount() [DataExtensionRowCount("My_Data_Extension")].

As to the major issue, your internet browser is likely timing out the task as it is taking too long due to the large amount of data being called.  You may want to introduce something that pulls small amounts of records and then use a next button to then pull the next set of records and so on.